# How to hook into a framework method?

Tags: ios, frameworks, hook, theos, tweak

I want to hook a iOS App and modify some `viewController` by use `Theos/tweak`. But these ViewController are defined on dynamic Framework. Is that cause the hook code in `Tweak.x` be disabled? The code can be build and installed successfully. Just the hook didn't work. How to fix it? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook any method in any class, dump the header file for the target class and select any method, the hook would look like below.

```
%hook ClassName

-(return type)MethodName{
     
    }

%end
```

Please see this for more info.
https://iphonedev.wiki/index.php/Logos#.25hook